# How do I pass a function pointer to cuPy Raw kernel in Python?

Tags: python, cuda, cupy

I am using **cuPy** to call raw CUDA kernels in Python scripts. I am able to load the simple standalone CUDA kernels in my Python script but I don't know the syntax to use if my CUDA kernel requires a function pointer as an argument. How do I pass a function pointer to a device function?

**Sample CUDA Kernel Requiring Function Pointer as Argument:**

```
extern "C" 
{
    // substraction
    __device__ float substractValues(float a, float b)
    {
        float value = a - b;
        return value;
    }
    typedef float(*FuncPtrSubstraction)(float, float, float, float, float);
    __device__ FuncPtrSubstraction d_ptrSubstraction = substractValues;

    // addition
    __device__ float addValues(float a, float b)
    {
        float sum = a + b;
        return sum;
    }
    typedef float(*FuncPtrAddition)(float, float, float, float, float);
    __device__ FuncPtrAddition d_ptrAddition = addValues;

    // main Kernel
    __global__ void applyMatricesOperation(float (*funcPtrOperation)(float, float),
        const float* A, 
        const float* B, 
        float* C, 
        int rows, 
        int cols) 
    {
        int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

        if (col < cols && row < rows) 
        {
            int index = row * cols + col;
            C[index] = funcPtrOperation(A[index] , B[index]); // A[index] + B[index]; OR A[index] - B[index]
            printf("computed...\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I tried to use **cuPy**'s `RawModule()` to load my CUDA code and then used `get_global()` to get my already defined function pointer on the device side. The code is working **but I am getting an exception while trying to read the results**

> cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered

```
import cupy as cp

# Define the CUDA kernel code
kernel_code = """
extern "C" {
    __device__ float addValues(float a, float b)
    {
        float sum = a + b;
        return sum;
    }
    typedef float(*FuncPtrAddition)(float, float);
    __device__ FuncPtrAddition d_ptrAddition = addValues;

    __global__ void addMatrices(float (*funcPtrAddValues)(float, float),
        const float* A,
        const float* B,
        float* C,
        int rows,
        int cols)
    {
        int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        printf("computed...");

        if (col < cols && row < rows) 
        {
            int index = row * cols + col;
            C[index] = funcPtrAddValues(A[index], B[index]);
        }
    }
}
"""

# Create a RawModule from the kernel code
raw_module = cp.RawModule(code=kernel_code)

# Load the addMatrices kernel from the module
addMatrices_kernel = raw_module.get_function("addMatrices")

# Define the dimensions for your matrix
rows, cols = 3, 3

# Allocate device memory for input and output arrays
A = cp.random.rand(rows, cols).astype(cp.float32)
B = cp.random.rand(rows, cols).astype(cp.float32)
C = cp.empty((rows, cols), dtype=cp.float32)

# Define grid and block dimensions
block_dim = (3, 3)
grid_dim = (rows // block_dim[0], cols // block_dim[1])

# Launch the kernel, passing the function pointer as an argument
funcPtr = raw_module.get_global("d_ptrAddition")
addMatrices_kernel(grid_dim, block_dim, (funcPtr, A, B, C, rows, cols))

# Copy the result back to the host
result = C.get()
print(result)
```

Comment: You almost certainly can't

Comment: @talonmies: How about if I put the whole CUDA code into `cupy.RawModule()` and then get my the `FuncPtrSubstraction` using cupy's `get_global()`?

Comment: Cuda doesn't expose device functions as module symbols, so also no. There us a design pattern jn CUDA to run a setup kernel to populate device symbols with function pointers, but I don't know if that can work in cupy

Comment: @talonmies: Maybe it can work. Please have a look at my update. I put a `printf()` statement in the kernel and it is printing but I am getting an exception while trying to read the results in `C`.

Comment: You cannot perform static assignment of the function pointer value. To quote my last comment again "... run a setup kernel to populate device symbols with function pointers"

Answer (score 1):

@talonmies was right that you can't pass function pointers as a kernel argument.

However, if you can ensure these kernels and device functions are kept in the same CUmodule (in CuPy's terms, keep them in the same `RawModule`) and use C++17 to compile them, templates can come to rescue!

```py
import cupy as cp


code = r"""
__device__ int a_plus_b(const int& a, const int& b) {
    return a + b;
}

__device__ int a_minus_b(const int& a, const int& b) {
    return a - b;
}

template<auto Func>
__global__ void my_kernel(const int* a, const int* b, int* out, int N) {
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < N) {
        out[tid] = Func(a[tid], b[tid]);
    }
}
"""

mod = cp.RawModule(code=code,
                   options=("-std=c++17",),
                   name_expressions=('my_kernel<a_plus_b>', 'my_kernel<a_minus_b>'))
plus_ker = mod.get_function('my_kernel<a_plus_b>')
minus_ker = mod.get_function('my_kernel<a_minus_b>')

a = cp.arange(5, dtype=cp.int32)
b = cp.arange(5, dtype=cp.int32) + 5
c = cp.empty_like(a)
plus_ker((1,), (5,), (a, b, c, 5))
print(f"{c=}")
minus_ker((1,), (5,), (a, b, c, 5))
print(f"{c=}")
```

Output:

```
c=array([ 5,  7,  9, 11, 13], dtype=int32)
c=array([-5, -5, -5, -5, -5], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works (Upvoted), it would be nice if someone could comment on how this approach affects performance. Found this comment by NVIDIA regarding performance decrease due the use of function pointers here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/device-function-pointers-is-it-possible-to-use-them-in-a-useful-way/42567/3?u=newprogrammer

Comment: templating, as used in this answer, shouldn't have the same performance concerns as function pointer usage.  The templating approach here allows the compiler to have full visibility into the code path being executed, at compile time.  As in all cases where performance is the question, there is no substitute for benchmarking.